# Tried using setFormula in Google scripts but keep getting an error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to use vlookup with setFormula but kept getting the error Missing ) after argument list. (line 22, file "Code")

my code was:

```
 sh.getRange("I"+row).setFormula(vlookup("H"+row,Roster!A:B,2,false));
```

I changed it to:

```
sh.getRange("I"+row).setFormula('=vlookup("H"+row,Roster!A:B,2,false)');
```

now the script runs but i get the error in sheets: Unknown range name: ROW

help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
sh.getRange("I"+row).setFormula('=vlookup(H'+row+',Roster!A:B,2,false)');
```

Below is an example to concatenate a string with a variable in Google script

```
var myVar = "Jack Brown"
var newString = 'My variable value: ' + myVar + '. My name' //Correct Syntax
Logger.log(newString) // will log: My variable value: Jack Brown. My name

//Below is an example of incorrect syntax as used in your code
newString = 'My variable value: + myVar +. My name'  //incorrect Syntax
Logger.log(newString) // Will log: My variable value: + myVar +. My name
```

Similarly, in your case to concatenate `row` variable to your formula string, you would do the following.

```
'=vlookup(H'+row+',Roster!A:B,2,false)'
```

And let assume `row = 2`, then the above string be formatted as

```
'=vlookup(H2,Roster!A:B,2,false)'
```

Comment: thank you so much!  that made it work. yeah, it was recognizing "row" as a string, instead of as a function. much appreciated!

Comment: If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: check mark done :) i actually upvoted it but it's not being shown public yet.  Thanks again!